# Using CSP (Content Security Policy) with a custom protocol

Tags: protocols, content-security-policy, custom-protocol, bankid

I'm in a bit of a pinch, developing a fund broker site.

As part of our security policies, [CSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) is implemented across our servers, but now, we're implementing communication with desktop software supplied by Scandinavian banks ([BankID](https://www.bankid.com/en/)).

With this, a problem arises: to open the BankID desktop software, a link should be clicked with a custom protocol, looking like this:

```
bankid://?orderref=[GUID]&autostarttoken=[GUID]
```

As I'm sure you understand, I'm having serious problems allowing this link through our CSP policies. My searches have yielded no results, and I have run out of ideas.

I have tried attempting to allow a wildcard domain under the protocol thus:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' bankid://*;
```

It works perfectly if I turn off CSP, so it's definitely the issue.

Anyone have any experience with this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT

After a few more hours searching, I found the following on the [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Apps/Security):

> We need an application delivery mechanism that provides assurances on app integrity and authenticity, and also allows for well-defined application & privilege scope enforcement so integrity can be maintained at runtime.

And further:

> Privileged and certified apps will be accessed via a unique scheme (app://). The domain will correspond to the app id.

I'm not sure if this would be applicable, but if I read this right, it means that Mozilla are considering how to tackle this very issue.

Answer (score 15):

It seems that you were very close to the solution, you only have to alter the syntax a little bit. By removing the slashes it should work just fine.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' bankid:;
```

To summarize:

- Quotes ("'): NO
- Slashes (//): NO
- Colon (:): YES